# How to get bounding shape for wrapped text in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm creating a p5 project in which I create text from a string, wrap it using the 'WORD' option and add it to the canvas. As an example:

```
let font;

function preload() {
  font = loadFont('SomeFont.otf');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(220);
  enteredText = 'This is an exmple of a long text that should split';
  textWrap(WORD);
  textSize(30);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textFont(font);
  textLeading(0.83 * 30);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  
  text(enteredText, width / 2, height / 2, 20 , 20);
}
```

I'd like to get a bounding shape for the text, in order to add some images on the frame.
How can I get this shape?
I thought about using `textBounds()`, but I also don't have the multiline string since `textWrap()` is doing it for me.
Any ideas? Re-writing `textWrap()` by myself feels like an overkill since there are so many properties for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That was a long time ago.  Maybe you know the answer already... In your code
enteredText, width / 2, height / 2, 20 , 20);
Since your chara ter size is 39, with 20,20 ^ here you will not be be able to prin even one letter. Instead of 20, 20 it should be 390, 400, for example.  You would adjust the numbers to your taste.  بنللي

Comment: Use code block to separate out the code change suggestions listed by you. Also please correct some typos